# com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found

Tags: google-bigquery, talend

When using a Talend bigquery input component (BQ java api) to read from bigquery, I get the following error (for a long running job) -

```
Exception in component tBigQueryInput_4
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Not found: Table rand-cap:_f000fcf374688fc5e7da50a4c0c04ba228d993c3.anon0849eba05949a62962f218a0433d6ee82bf13a7b",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "Not found: Table rand-cap:_f000fcf374688fc5e7da50a4c0c04ba228d993c3.anon0849eba05949a62962f218a0433d6ee82bf13a7b"
}
```

Is this because of the "[temporary](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#temporary_and_permanent_tables)" table that bq creates when querying results not being available after 24hrs. Or is it because rate limit was exceeded since I am querying a large table ?

In either case, how can I find more details on this error and what steps should I take to prevent this ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem in Talend, there are other users describing your issue: https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=44734

> Google Bigquery has a property i.e. Allowlargeresults but its not there in TBigqueryinput.

> Hi there - I am currently using Talend open studio v6.1.1 and this issue still exists.

Comment: I've noticed you can set that property only if you specify a destination table, which doesn't make sense from a client application point of view.

Comment: Also, the 404 error we get from bigquery api isn't very descriptive of what is causing it (rate limit vs expiration).